# Very poor print quality with Linux Libertine - XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, libertine

I'm experiencing a strange problem (to me) with the Linux Libertine O font. I compile a document like this with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional, Lowercase}]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet $P(h) \propto height(parent(h))-height(h)$
\end{document}
```

When I print it, the quality of the text in the Libertine typeface is really, really bad, especially if compared to the one of the piece of math which is in the TeX Gyre Pagella typeface: the latter looks perfect. So it seems to me it has to be a problem of printing Linux Libertine, and it cannot have to do with the printer itself. I just can't figure out what could be the problem. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Does the PDF look fine in your reader? If it does, and while I'd consider this sorta on-topic for TeX.SX, you'll probably have better luck asking on SU. But that's just like... my *opinion*, man. :-)

Comment: Yes no problem at all in the reader. Excuse my incompetence, what do you mean by "asking on SU"? Thank you anyway

Comment: Everything looks totally fine here, also when printing the document. There's probably some issue with your printer.

Comment: @flor Sean means superuser.com

Comment: Yes, I meant http://www.superuser.com :-) It's one of the original sites of the StackExchange network. Thanks @ArthurReutenauer

Comment: Thank you! Well @Sverre I doubt that the problem is the printer, because as I said the TGPagella looks fine and I've printed several documents, all written with the same system and mainly with LM font, with that printer, and I've never noted this problem. In fact, it happens only with Linux Libertine.

Comment: I tested the example and printed it -- there is no bad print quality. It must be a printer issue or a corrupted printer driver

Comment: Ok @ChristianHupfer it must be like that. It is just funny. I will try with other printers, thank you a lot!

Comment: @flor I don't mean that your printer doesn't work, but some printers might struggle to print characters from certain fonts. The problem either resides with a printer driver or there's some faulty coding within the font itself. Either way, I don't think there's anything we can do here.

Comment: Also, you might wanna submit a bug report to the Linux Libertine repository, with details about your printer.

Comment: Ok I will. It is a library's printer, I'm gonna check it and report the issue on the LL repo. Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't be too sure it's _not_ xelatex (and friends). Back in Ye Olde Days, converting DVI to postscript to PDF would sometimes have the reverse problem: Lousy on-screen fonts that printed fine. The problem was with one of the tools in the toolchain, hence would be on-topic here.

Comment: Perhaps you can upload a one-page PDF somewhere that people can check out?

Comment: @alexis If the problem resided with `xelatex`, then we'd expect others who compile the OP's MWE with `xelatex` to experience the same problem. As far as the comments above state, we don't.

Comment: Not `xelatex` per se, but the way the whole system is configured on the OP's computer. (I shoud have made that clear; it's not a problem everyone has.) My point is, it doesn't have to be the printer: it _could_ be that the PDF output is defective--and it's easy to check.

Comment: Here it is, @alexis [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxFqcQCV2d2SRXM2d3k3Ni05eFU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @flor: I used the link you provided and printed the sample page. Looks fine for me